# Getting a NaN even though im using parseInt for additive equation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing a project for class, it's a paper rock scissor type game. I have the game working fine, I'm now simply trying to make it so that you play for a best of three scenario.

I coded it (at least I tried to) so that when you win, playerwin gets a point, and when you lose, compwin gets a point. When one of you has two points, you get an alert saying you won or lost.

I ran through stack trying to find out how to do this on my own, since this is new to me. Tried my best, came up short. Im not getting any actual errors, its just not doing what I want. I thought that parseInt-'ing the variable would make it a number, but it's coming up as NaN, so its clearly not. What am I doing wrong?

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lwj2zny5/

Html -

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Lizard, paper, scissors, spock, rock</h1>

<div id="images">
<img class="game-image" src="Images/lizard.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="1"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/paper.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="2"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/scissors.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="3"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/spock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="4"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/rock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="5"/>
</div>

<div id="win">
</div>

<div id="score">
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="unit2.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS -

```
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.game-image', function(event) {
    var value = $(event.target).data('value');
    var win; 
    var playerwin = parseInt($.trim($(this).html()));
    var compwin = parseInt($.trim($(this).html()));
    var comproll = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    //$('#comproll').html('Result: '+comproll)
    if (comproll === 1) {
      comp = "Lizard";
    } else if (comproll === 2) {
      comp = "paper";
    } else if (comproll === 3) {
      comp = "scissors";
    } else if (comproll === 4) {
      comp = "Spock";
    } else if (comproll === 5) {
      comp = "Rock";
    }

    if (value === comproll) {
      win = "This ends in a tie, computer chose " + comp + " also.";
    } else if (value === 1) {
      if (comproll === 2 || comproll === 4) {
        win = "You win, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++playerwin);
      } else if (comproll === 3 || comproll === 5) {
        win = "You lose, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++compwin);
      }
    } else if (value === 2) {
      if (comproll === 4|| comproll ===  5) {
        win = "You win, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++playerwin);
      } else if (comproll === 1 ||comproll ===  3) {
        win = "You lose, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++compwin);
      }
    } else if (value === 3) {
      if (comproll === 1 || comproll ===  2) {
        win = "You win, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++playerwin);
      } else if (comproll === 4 || comproll ===  5) {
        win = "You lose, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++compwin);
      }
    } else if (value === 4) {
      if (comproll === 3 || comproll ===  5) {
        win = "You win, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++playerwin);
      } else if (comproll === 1 || comproll ===  2) {
        win = "You lose, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++compwin);
      }
    } else if (value === 5) {
      if (comproll === 1 || comproll ===  3) {
        win = "You win, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++playerwin);
      } else if (comproll === 2 || comproll ===  4) {
        win = "You lose, comp choose " + comp + ".";
        $(this).html(++compwin);
      }

    }

    $('#score').text(playerwin, compwin);
        if (playerwin == 2) {
            alert("You Won");
        } else if (compwin == 2) { 
            alert("You lose");
        }
    $('#win').text(win);
  }); //closes play function

}); // closes function
```

Yes i know this is bulky code, but what we're learning atm is if/else statements so thats what im using.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: You're using === when you compare `value` to `comproll`, so you're testing a string against a number. That said, what is the rest of your code doing? $(this) is an image element, none of those have innerHTML according to your HTML, so what do you expect comproll to be?

Comment: What do you expect `$(this).html()` to be (when assigning `playerwin` and `compwin`)? The `.game-image` element just clicked on is an `<img>` and has no HTML content inside of it. you're calling `parseInt` on an empty string.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Possibly not; IIRC, jQuery number-ifies `.data` results if it does not change the string representation of value. (But I may be wrong, I haven't checked.)

Comment: Cleaned up fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lwj2zny5/2/

Comment: Well what Ithought it was doing was when the image was clicked, it would compared the random number generated to my selection. Based upon the win or loss in the if/else statement, it would then produce a statement stating you won or lost, THEN add one to the corresponding variable. Clearly that is not working, and from what Apsillers and Mike are saying, that doesn't work. I am kind of piecing this together from what I googled since this is new to me. How do I go about writing it so that i test or call it correctly?

Comment: Miniragnarok, what did you clean up exactly? I just want to know so that in the future when I post JSfiddle's I can post clean code so that people don't need to clean it up for me. I would like to be as easy to help as possible.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer First up, if you use @ in your reply then I will be notified that someone has replied to me. As for the fiddle, I used the TidyUp button, I removed the body tag from the HTML, I removed the scripts from there as well, I added jQuery by using the options on the left of the screen, and I replaced the images with online placeholder images.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer There's loads of sites that can act as placeholder images. I used http://placekitten.com/ here but http://placehold.it/ is pretty great too.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer Check out this tutorial on how to use jsfiddle. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Awesome, I will keep all of that in mind for the future. I appreciate you doing that for me, I was not aware that these things mattered. But considering im the one asking for help, the least I can do is make it as easy as possible for you guys to help me. I will read that tutorial now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  var compwin = 0;
  var playerwin = 0;
  $(document).on('click', '.game-image', function(event) {
    var value = $(event.target).data('value');
    var win; 
    var comproll = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

then

```
    $("#win").text(win);
    $('#score').text("Player = " + playerwin + ", Computer = " + compwin);
    if (playerwin == 2) {
        alert("You Won");
        compwin = 0;
        playerwin = 0;
        $('#score').text("");
        $("#win").text("");
    } else if (compwin == 2) {
        alert("You lose");
        compwin = 0;
        playerwin = 0;
        $('#score').text("");
        $("#win").text("");
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, this take me a huge leap ahead. Curious though, do i keep the $(this).html(++compwin); as it is since there is no "this" to refer to. Also people are telling me an image is not html, so thats part of my problem, so i assume this would not work and i need to change it.

Comment: Oh my, it works. You are a jedi master of coding. I appreciate your help immensely and thank you for being able to read past my issues and see what I was ATTEMPTING to do. Thank you!

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer Just to clarify your confusion a little: an image doesn't have *child* HTML content. For example, `<div>hello <span>world</span></div>` is a `<div>` that contains the HTML `hello <span>world</span>`. While a `<div>` or `<a>` can contain HTML content, an image tag can't contain any HTML inside of it. A link can contain text, for example, but doesn't make sense for an image to contain something; it's just an image. For example, `<img src="...">hello world</img>` doesn't make any sense: what meaning would text have inside of an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).on('click', '.game-image', function(event) {
   ...
   var playerwin = parseInt($.trim($(this).html()));
   ...
```

**$(this)** refers to the clicked image. Images do not contain .html()

Comment: So do I just delete the .html, or substitute in .img or something? Sorry the examples I found all used html so I just assumed it would be the same.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish, so I have no idea.

Comment: Well what I am trying to do is when the image was clicked, it would compared the random number generated to my selection. Based upon the win or loss in the if/else statement, it would then produce a statement stating you won or lost, THEN add one to the corresponding variable. So the If/else statement would add +1 to the variable. Upon reaching 2, an alert would pop saying you've won or lost the best of three. Clearly that is not working. I am kind of piecing this together from what I googled since this is new to me.

Comment: I think you need: var playerwin = parseInt(value);

Comment: Isn't playerwin and compwin the number of wins for each player? Why are you looking at the img data-value?

Comment: Because I don't know what im doing hence my question. What I have it looking at I dont fully understand. You are correct, playerwin and compwin are number of wins for each player. I changed the variables to what Diodeus said, var playerwin = parseInt(value);  - but am now trying to write how to add them in the if/else statements. I tried compwin = $(++compwin); but that just added it value number that each pic is assigned. I then tried compwin = $(++ 1); but thats giving an error. Currently googling for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you are getting the scores from image html instead of having variables tracking it. I created a jsfiddle trying to understand your code. But I cleaned it up too much and looks little bit different.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/uzagumu7/22/

I created short functions trying to make the code cleaner.

```
var playerScore = 0;
var computerScore = 0;

var choices = ["Lizard", "Paper", "Scissors", "Spock", "Rock"];

var computerRoll = function () {
    return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
}

var resultOfGame = function (playerChoice, computerChoice) {
    if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
        return 0; // tie
    } else if (
    ((playerChoice === 1) && ((computerChoice === 2) || (computerChoice === 4))) || 
    ((playerChoice === 2) && ((computerChoice === 4) || (computerChoice === 5))) || 
    ((playerChoice === 3) && ((computerChoice === 1) || (computerChoice === 2))) || 
    ((playerChoice === 4) && ((computerChoice === 3) || (computerChoice === 5))) || 
    ((playerChoice === 5) && ((computerChoice === 1) || (computerChoice === 3)))) 
    { 
        // player wins
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Newer version of jsfiddle has image with usemap. Also removed the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/uzagumu7/78/